# Heroku Python No module named Mysql

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I want to use MySQL queries in a Python bot and deploy it to Heroku. But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "bot.py", line 2, in <module>  
import mysql.connector  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

My requirements file contains:

```
pyodbc==4.0.22   
MySQL-python
```

The deploy goes well but when running the code it shows the error.

This is the import:

```
import mysql.connector
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several MySQL libraries for Python (and most other languages).

[MySQL-Python](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1) is an old, legacy library:

> This is the legacy (1.x) version of MySQLdb. While it is still being maintained, there will not be a lot of new feature development.

You probably want to use a different library, but if you really want to use this one you [should be importing `MySQLdb`, not `mysql.connector`](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#some-examples).

You are currently importing `mysql.connector`, which looks to be [this library](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html). To install it from PyPI, look for [the `mysql-connector-python` package](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/).

These libraries are not drop-in replacements for each other. Depending how you've written your code, you might need to do some refactoring.

Note that it's usually a good idea to install dependencies in the same way in development and production. That is, if you're using `requirements.txt` and `pip` on Heroku, do the same thing locally. Add libraries to your `requirements.txt` and then use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install them. This helps to minimize surprises when you deploy.